# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list despite no missing ')' in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why am I receiving this error when my button click calls this function?

```
function ShowFaultMessage(message) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Message/',
        data: JSON.stringify(message),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(result) {
            var w = window.open("/Home/Message", "Fault Message", "width=400, height=400");
            $(w.document.body).html(result.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

I've looked at the other questions about this error, but none seem to apply here. I appear to have all my brackets and parenthesis present.

This is the button that calls the function. It appears ok as well:

```
 return new HtmlString(string.Format("<input type='submit' id='btnShowFault' onclick='ShowFaultMessage({0})' value='Fault' />", item.Fault.Message));
```

Comment: look at the generated html for the submit button. I bet it's a mess (attributes with single quotes instead of double, garbage in the onclick event handler parameter...)

Comment: is it giving any line number?

Comment: How is that garbage in the event handler parameter? It's a string that's being passed in as a parameter. I assume javascript can handle that...

Comment: This is the generated HTML for the button:
<input type="submit" id="btnShowFault" onclick="ShowFaultMessage(Test Fault Message)" value="Fault">. Seems fine to me....

Comment: Suman. It gives me line 1 of my main view. The code above is on a partial view called by my main view. So not sure that line number helps much.

Comment: Wait, where are you seeing this error?  In your result.responseText?  If so, the error is coming from the server side, and we would need to see your server side code, as well as have more information before we could give you an answer.

Comment: I figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put double quotes when building my HTMLString for the button in the parameter for the function call like so:

```
return new HtmlString(string.Format("<input type='submit' id='btnShowFault' onclick='ShowFaultMessage(\"{0}\")' value='Fault' />", item.Fault.Message));
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you need double quote or single quote when passing a model value to javascript function consider it as a string value rather than a javascript value. This is the same case when using it on jquery or appending the model value.

```
var test = "alert_container";
foreach (var item in Model.ErrorLists)
       {
           <script>
               jsfunction("@item.prop");

                 or

               $('#@test').append('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in">' +
                                            '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' +
                                            '<strong>Error:</strong> @item.ErrorMessage </div>');
           </script>



       }
```